# UIPopoverController getting crashing in iPhone in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode, uipopovercontroller

I am working with the UIPopViewController.I have a BarButton with add option.If I click on the ‘+’ popup has to come.It is working fine when I gave connection in storyBoard.But If I am calling using the code,it is not working.It is crashing..My code is like this..

```
@IBAction func addingData(sender: AnyObject) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let playerInformationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PopView") as? PopView
    playerInformationViewController!.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover
    playerInformationViewController!.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 300)
    playerInformationViewController!.delegate = self

    let popoverPresentationViewController = playerInformationViewController!.popoverPresentationController
    popoverPresentationViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any    
    popoverPresentationViewController?.delegate = self    
    popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = sender as? UIBarButtonItem

    presentViewController(playerInformationViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "test" {
        let popoverViewController = segue.destinationViewController 
        popoverViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        popoverViewController.popoverPresentationController!.delegate = self
    }
}
```

The error Message I am getting is …

> UIPopoverPresentationController: 0x7fdda8cd4ad0>) should have a non-nil    sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.’**

Can anyone tell me what mistake I did.Please clarify my doubt.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I delete the connection in StoryBoard and using the above code,It is not working.

Comment: The above code only the barbutton code.

Comment: I gave IBAction connection to UIBarbutton.In that UIBarbutton IBAction method I wrote this code.

Comment: change your method to `@IBAction func addingData(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {` and then replace the previous action by this one.

Comment: Looks like your playerInformationViewController is not having popoverPresentationController. Check the popoverPresentationViewController reference.

Comment: Ya.It is working. @NDoc

Comment: @anushahrithi It is your custom delegate, show the code of method implementation and method calling using delegate.

Comment: Sorry I rectified it.Thank you so much @NDoc